# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Tags: calculus

derivative of $\frac{x}{1-x}$ is $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ whereas integral of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ is not $\frac{x}{1-x}$ ! Is not the fundamental theorem of calculus violated?

Comment: differs by a constant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your doubt is that you get $\dfrac 1{1-x}$ but not $\dfrac x{1-x}$.
In fact, they only differ by a constant:

$\;\;\dfrac 1{1-x}+C'$

$=\dfrac 1{1-x}-1+C$ (C' and C are just arbitrary constants)

$=\dfrac x{1-x}+C$

so both answers are correct. They are just different presentations of the same family of functions.